# Power supply terminals

Tags: power-supply, dc, terminal

I've been looking around at some power supplies that I am hoping to run a 400W 48V DC motor on. Currently I am looking at this one:

[Weidmuller PRO ECO 480W 42V-56V dc 10A](http://catalog.weidmueller.com/assets/PDF/1504130000_00_12.13_IS_PRO_ECO_480W_48V_10A.pdf)

My questions are about the output terminals.

1) Why are there specifically 3 negative terminals and 2 positive terminals?

2) Are the multiple terminal pairs for potentially connecting components in parallel?

3) Are the 13 and 14 terminals (see block diagram in pdf) there to attach a switch if required?

I would be greatful if anyone could help clear up any of those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The third negative is probably for use as a chassis ground (like the housing of a motor).

2) The multiple terminals are for connecting subsystems in parallel.  It's just a convenience thing.  If the output current was very high then it might be for running multiple conductors but 10 A isn't very exciting.

3) The '13' and '14' terminals are the connected to an internal relay. '13' and '14' will be shorted together when everything is OK and they will be open otherwise.  For example you could use this to run a big light to indicate that power is on or maybe enable/disable another power supply.

Answer (score -1):

so many languages...**hard to read**

```
 "three power supply units can be connected in parallel... set uniformly (±50 mV)
 - DC OK: LED green, *Relay ON*  Uout > 43.2 V DC
 - Overload, over temperature, short circuit: LED red, *Relay OFF* U out < 40.8 V DC"
 - Relay rating: 30 V AC/DC, 1 A
```